# \everymath, AMS equations, beamer, and tikz not working together

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, math-mode, amsmath

In a `beamer` document, I have `$` expressions embedded in displayed equations (using `tikz` to make, e.g., colored boxes around some expressions).  I put `\everymath{\displaystyle}` in the preamble so that these expressions aren't show in text style.  However, when the `$` expression is in an AMS equation environment rather than `equation`, this `\everymath` is not honored:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
  $\sum_i$ \$ expr\\                 % works
  \tikz \node {$\sum_i$ \$ in tikz}; % works
  \begin{equation}
    \tikz \node {$\sum_i$ tikz in equation}; % works
    \text{$\sum_i$ text in equation}         % works
  \end{equation}
  \begin{gather}
    \tikz \node {$\sum_i$ tikz in gather};   % problem
    \text{$\sum_i$ text in gather}           % works
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Note that this happens only inside `\tikz`, not `\text`; and only with the `beamer` document class.  I am intrigued: why does this happen?  And is there a simple workaround?

(Of course there is a simple workaround: put `\displaymath` in every `$` expression ... But maybe something more elegant?)

Comment: A very handful and simple method to highlight equations is provided by the `\tcbhighmath` command from the `tcolorbox` package. Using this, you don't have to do manual adjustments.

Comment: You basically can't use `\everymath` in LaTeX because math mode is used and abused behind the scenes in many unexpected ways.  I wouldn't trust something as intricate as Beamer to leave it alone at all.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, in my real document I also use `tikz` to draw arrows between nodes, so I think I want to stay with that (apart from not wanting to learn yet another package ...)
@Ryan: I read about this problem in the context of coloring equations.  I thought for `\displaystyle` it would not be an issue, because that will affect nothing that is not actually math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

egreg and percusse both provided answers that solved the problem for the test case I provided.  However, in my real document, things got a bit more complicated, so I thought I would share what I learned.

Specifically, I have one `\tikz` inside an `\intertext`, and that only works with percusse's solution.  On the other hand, I have one `$` expression inside a `tabular`, and that only works with egreg's solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

% percusse
\tikzset{execute at begin node={\everymath{\displaystyle}}} 

% egreg
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\donotcoloroutermaths{%
  \everymath{\everymath{\displaystyle\beamer@setmathcolor}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \tikz \node {$\sum_i$ tikz in gather};    % works with either solution
  \intertext{                               % works with percusse's solution
    \tikz \node {
      $\sum_i$ tikz in intertext
    };
  }
\end{gather}

\begin{tabular}{l}
  $\sum_i$                                  % works with egreg's solution
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

So in the end, I am using both solutions combined.

Answer (score 6):

Something that I'm not sure yet resets the math rendering (probably due to the box font settings or something related to the `gather` but I'm not really good at that math settings differences about `amsmath` package). So if you push the command to be executed at every start of the node, it looks like the problem is gone. Also I recommend `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,lmodern}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\tikzset{execute at begin node={\everymath{\displaystyle}}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\sum_i$ \$ expr\\                 % works
  \tikz \node {$\sum_i$ \$ in tikz}; % works
  \begin{equation}
    \tikz[baseline] \node {$\sum_i$ tikz in equation}; % works
    \text{$\sum_i$ text in equation}         % works
  \end{equation}
  \begin{gather}
    \tikz[baseline] \node {$\sum_i$ tikz in gather};   % problem
    \text{$\sum_i$ text in gather}           % works
  \end{gather}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`beamerbasecolor.sty` (loaded by `beamer.cls`) redefines `\start@gather` to execute `\donotcoloroutermaths` which in turn does

```
\everymath{\everymath{\beamer@setmathcolor}}
```

You can solve the issue by adding `\displaystyle`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\donotcoloroutermaths{%
  \everymath{\everymath{\displaystyle\beamer@setmathcolor}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \tikz \node {$\sum_i$ tikz in gather};
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

The fix should work also with `align` and the other `amsmath` environments.